Failed to initialize grpc::ClientReader (C2664 error)
Platform: Windows MSVC 2022 (v143)
C++ version: C++17
gRPC version: 1.60.0 (installed with vcpkg)
std::unique_ptr< grpc::ClientReader<MyData> > reader(
  stub->StreamService(&context, request)
);

It returns error C2664:

cannot convert parameter
'std::unique_ptrgrpc::ClientReader<MyData,std::default_deletegrpc::ClientReader<MyData>>::unique_ptr(const
std::unique_ptrgrpc::ClientReader<MyData,std::default_deletegrpc::ClientReader<MyData>>
&)': 1  from
'std::unique_ptrgrpc::ClientReaderInterface<MyData,std::default_deletegrpc::ClientReaderInterface<MyData>>'
to 'const
std::unique_ptrgrpc::ClientReader<MyData,std::default_deletegrpc::ClientReader<MyData>>
&'

I simply followed the example code in grpc C++ Basics tutorial, and stuck in this problem.

Stub->StreamService(&context, request) returns a smart pointer of ClientReaderInterface.
I tried to transfer ownership of this smart pointer to reader, which is type of ClientReader (child class of ClientReaderInterface), through std::move, but it failed. Instead, I succeeded with the method below.
auto client_reader_interface 
  = stub->StreamService(&context, request);
auto reader 
  = std::unique_ptr<grpc::ClientReader<MyData> >(
      static_cast<grpc::ClientReader<MyData>* >(
        client_reader_interface.release()
      )
    );

